# Hash string to MD5 in Python without encoding?

Tags: python, md5, hashlib

I'm trying to compare the hashes of passwords in a list I'm reading in a file to hashes found in some HTML. Using hashlib in Python 3.6 produces a hash different to the one found using online MD5 generators. This is due to the character prefix "b'" and "'" at the start and the end of the hash. This is added when the string is encoded as otherwise an error pops up saying it must be encoded to be hashed.

I have also tried using crypt but that does not give me the right hash needed. Otherwise I am stuck.

Here is my error message

```
File "md5hashing.py", line 23, in main
    wordlist_hash = hashlib.md5(wordlist_hash).digest()
TypeError: Unicode-objects must be encoded before hashing
```

The code I am using

```
wordlist_hash = wordlist[item]
        #wl_hash = wordlist_hash.encode('utf-8')
        wordlist_hash = hashlib.md5(wl_hash).digest()
```

Any help would be appreciated.